# ListView headers onBackPressed()

Tags: android, listview

I'm struggling with ListView and its header in Android. I'm using a ListFragment and in onViewCreated I'm doing this:

```
        View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.route_list_header, null);
        header.setLayoutParams(new       ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        getListView().addHeaderView(header);

        RouteAdapter adapter = new RouteAdapter(getActivity(), routes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
                fragment.showRoute(routes.get(position - 1).getRoutePoints());
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("map")
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

And it works OK, but the problem is when I change to another fragment and then I press back button. I can't add the header again because I've already called setAdater before (before stoping the fragment). What can I do?